# Delete an temporary/hidden file

Tags: command-prompt, windows-7-x64

I can see a file with `~$` prefix on my desktop when I make `dir/a` command in prompt. When I want to delete it I have a message `Impossible to find C:\Users\myname\Desktop\~$myfile.xlsx`

What this prefix mean ? Temporary, hidden file ? And how can I delete this file ?

PS: I'm using Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably this is a remaining temporary file. May be it was created when your pc turned off without regular system shutdown and MS Excell was open with this file loaded and modified without saving.

Try the following:

1. boot your Windows in safe mode.
2. try to delete.
3. reboot.

If this doesn't work:

1. boot in safe and DOS (prompt) mode.
2. go to your desktop folder (`cd c:\mypc\user\` etc etc).
3. type `attrib -$myfile.xlsx -r -h -s` (this makes your file not **r**ead only, not **h**idden and not a **s**ystem file) and then **enter** on your keyboard.
4. type `del -$myfile.xlsx` then **enter** and see what happens.
5. reboot.

If all this doesn't work it would be needed to modify ownership properties of the file, taking it for your user ownership or for an admin, then delete with rights. There is a small registry routine out there on the web to implement a "take ownership" option on the right click or your mouse on Windows. This can be helpful in some cases.

Comment: The way was to boot in safe mode and run the `attrib` command before, thanks. However I need to write the exact name `~$myfile.xlsx` otherwise `-` is interpreted as a comutator.

Comment: note that the command prompt in Windows is **not** DOS [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're trying to delete it through the command prompt or powershell.

If you're using PowerShell, PS is going to interpret "$myfile" as a variable, and since "$myfile" is blank, it's going to try and delete "~.xslx".

If you're using the standard Windows command prompt, then you should just be able to run "del ~$myfile.xlsx".

Comment: `del ~$myfile.xlsx` return me `Impossible to find C:\Users\myname\Desktop\~$myfile.xlsx`. That's the object of this question.

Comment: Are you using PS or CMD? If you're using PS, try using the "rm" command and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: in powershell `~` expands to the user's home folder, and `$` is the sigil for the variable, so you must escape those characters. In cmd it's not necessary

Comment: I'm using `cmd`.